# Passport/visa check traveling by coach from London to Paris

Tags: visas, international-travel, schengen-visas, borders, passport-stamps

I will be traveling by coach (Flixbus) from London to Paris. I'm an Indonesian citizen with both tourist visas for the UK and Schengen area. From my understanding, there are usually two border control checks (one for leaving the UK and one before entering the Eurotunnel). France will be my first point of entry in the Schengen area so will the French authority stamp my passport when we get to the border control? and will the British authority also stamp my passport for exiting the UK?

Answer (score 4):

Border control for both countries happen together *before* the tunnel no matter which direction you're traveling in. ([Source](https://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/trade/coach-operators/your-journey/)). These happens by a special agreement between the UK and France ("juxtaposed controls").

The UK does not use exit stamps for *anyone* -- but you can expect the French guards on the British side to stamp your passport with for a Schengen entry.

[Anecdotal reports suggest](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35929/visa-free-travel-no-entry-or-exit-stamp-given-between-uk-and-french-border) that the French sometimes don't give an entry stamp. If that happens, try to politely insist on getting one; it may create trouble for you when you leave the Schengen area if you can't document when you entered.

Comment: +1 with the caveat that this may change depending on when food89 is traveling and what the results of Brexit is on border relations between Feb EU and the UK.

Comment: @Sarriesfan Juxtapose controls aren't expected to change after brexit, in fact it was reported last year that the Netherlands may join these controls. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-43002908

Comment: @BritishSam that's what they are reporting but at the moment particularly after the way some Brexiters are upset by the "Special place in hell" comment I would not be surprised if even  deals like this are not affected at the last minute

Comment: I recently went on an overnight bus London-Paris (Flixbus) and the bus wasn't even checked by the French at Cheriton despite the passenger list including at least one American and one Brazilian