# Didnt receive Entry stamp while entering France via Bus from London

Tags: schengen-visas, passport-stamps

I traveled to Paris last year from London on my Indian passport with a Schengen Visa (From the French embassy). I am a UK resident with BRP. As my visit was via bus and the immigration officer was in a hurry to clear the bus, he didn't stamp my passport stating when I entered France.

Now when I made my last visit to Italy this summer, I was interrogated on arrival because I got an exit stamp from France, but no entry stamp. They were worried that I might have overstayed during my last visit, which is not the case.

Now I want to apply again to France to get another Schengen visa (mine expired last week). I am now worried that they might reject it for the same reason.

Shall I be worried? It's not my mistake, I didn't know then that I needed to get the passport stamped.

**Edit**: I stumbled upon this article, https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76574/90955 It looks like french immigration officers do miss stamping quite often. Hope this wont be blocker, if someone can shed some light that would be useful

Comment: yes, it was that answer I was think of while writing my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases where this happens, it is wise to retain the ticket which can **assist** on proving you entered on a specific date.

Also check on which date the visa was issued. If it was, by chance, less than 90 days before the exit then that would be proof enough.

Write short letter explaining the situation and send it along with the application. There is really nothing more that you can do.

This probaly happens occasionally, so unless there no other reasons, a new visa will probably be issued. That in itsself will clear any doubts about your travel record.

Comment: Yes, my visa was issued 90 days before the exit day stamp from france. That should be fine . Thanks :)

Comment: @susanoochidori meantion that also in the letter.

Answer (score 1):

You may get hassled and they might have to look into it to confirm your travel dates (not sure about the details here or what is stored on computer systems). Better for future reference to get a stamp when going in *and* out of the schengen area.

Personal story: when entering Lithuania from Kaliningrad, 100m after clearing immigration, I returned because of curiosity about the lack of a stamp, and upon asking, they stamped my passport then. Not exactly sure what would have happened if I didn't ask